# Debugging CLR proc exception

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, visual-studio-2008

I get a `transactionabortedexception` when I run a CLR proc in debug mode
and no line number information or anything to help with 
where the exception is.

I am running VS2008 and SQL 2005.

how do you debug it?

Answer (score 0):

You might be in debug mode, but if you don't have access to the PDB's of the referenced assemblies, you won't get line number.

The stack trace should get you most of the way there to figure out where the exception is.  Or are you saying you are not getting any stack trace at all?

Comment: It seems it completed ok sort of. I remove the transaction and it completes ok but with the transaction is gives the exception and I have a trans.Complete() at the end??